# Compare only date part ot time.Time in Golang

Tags: date, go, comparison

Assume the following two dates. The date is the same, however the time is different.

```
t1, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", "2016-01-01 12:12:12.0")
t2, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05", "2016-01-01 18:19:20.0")
```

I would compare them using `Format()`, but am not sure if that's the best way, especially when different timezones are at play.

```
if t1.Format("2006-01-02") == t2.Format("2006-01-02") {
    // dates are equal, don't care about time.
}
```

Is this a good approach, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can either truncate the time to the day:

```
t1.Truncate(24*time.Hour).Equal(t2.Truncate(24*time.Hour))
```

Or you can compare the year and day separately:

```
t1.Year() == t2.Year() && t1.YearDay() == t2.YearDay()
```